Lexical scope issues when assigning event methods
I would like to create a Javascript class that provides various methods for storing and manipulating data (ex.: a simple counter). When constructed, the class would also create DOM elements that access those methods (ex.: a button that adds 1 to the counter).
However, I quickly run into a lexical scoping issue. In the example below, the this in this.add_to_value(1) no longer refers to the Counter class, and so the desired behaviour is not achieved.
How can I take advantage of the jQuery event methods while still keeping things neatly organized into classes?
class Counter{

    constructor(initial_value){
  
        // Initial Counter value
        this.value = initial_value
    
        // Button that adds 1 to the Counter
        this.counter_button = $('<button>+1</button>')
           .appendTo('body')
           .click(function(){

               // PROBLEM: 'this' no longer refers to the Counter class
               this.add_to_value(1)
           }) 
  }

  // Method for adding to the Counter's value
  add_to_value(added_value){
    this.value += added_value
  } 
}

// Example: create a Counter with an initial value of 10
new Counter(10)


In constructor -> var thisCounter = this.  In click handler -> thisCounter.add_to_value(1);

Change your function to use an arrow function.. eg.   function(){   to -> () => { this is bound to the containing function, and your function() has created a new one.  Arrow functions keep the existing this context.
